# Set value File from picture in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-image-picker

I have so many data to send to my backend. I made a class for all data I need. I named it `service_data` and it contains

```
class ServiceData {
 File? fileBukuServis;
 File? fileSTNK;
 File? fileOwnerManual;
}
```

after that, I want to pick image from camera and set it into the data above. I use package `image_picker` and I use this function to set the data

```
class _DetailCarState extends State<DetailCar> {
  ServiceData serviceData = ServiceData();
  final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();

  Future pickImage({File? imageData, html.File? htmlImageData}) async {
    final XFile? image =
      await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera, imageQuality: 50);
    if (image != null) {
      setState(() {
        imageData = File(image.path);
      });
    }
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print(serviceData.fileBukuServis!.path);
    }
  }
}
```

and for pick image, I use this

```
ElevatedButton(
 style: ButtonStyle(
   backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
    Colors.red[800])),
 onPressed: () {
   if (kIsWeb) {
     pickImage(htmlImageData: serviceData.htmlfileBukuServis);
   }
   pickImage(imageData: serviceData.fileBukuServis);
 },
 child: const Text('Ambil gambar'))
```

and when I pict image from camera, `fileBukuServis` inside `serviceData` always null. How can I set the data from imagepicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the method you use to pick the image, you just modify the local variable `imageData` and return nothing.

```
Future pickImage({File? imageData, html.File? htmlImageData}) async {
    final XFile? image =
      await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera, imageQuality: 50);
    if (image != null) {
      setState(() {
        imageData = File(image.path); // Won't do anything since variable is in local scope
      });
    }
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print(serviceData.fileBukuServis!.path);
    }
  }
```

You can directly change the `serviceData.fileBukuServis` variable. Here is the modified code:

```
class ServiceData {
   File? fileBukuServis;
   File? htmlfileBukuServis;
   File? fileSTNK;
   File? fileOwnerManual;
}

enum ServiceDataFile{
   fileBukuServis,
   htmlfileBukuServis,
}

class _DetailCarState extends State<DetailCar> {
  ServiceData serviceData = ServiceData();
  final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();

  Future pickImage(ServiceDataFile fileMode) async {
    final XFile? image =
        await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera, imageQuality: 50);
    if (image != null) {
      if(fileMode == ServiceDataFile.fileBukuServis){
         serviceData.fileBukuServis = File(image.path);
      } else {
         serviceData.htmlfileBukuServis = File(image.path);
      }
      setState((){});

      if(kDebugMode){
         print(image.path);
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      style: ButtonStyle(
        backgroundColor:
            MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.red[800]),
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        pickImage(kIsWeb ? ServiceDataFile.htmlfileBukuServis : ServiceDataFile.fileBukuServis);
      },
      child: const Text('Ambil gambar'),
    );
  }
}
```

Also, your `ServiceData` class didn't have a `htmlfileBukuServis` field. Make sure to add it in your code.